# Opposite of victim blaming?

Tags: fallacies, justice

If victim blaming is the fallacy of automatically assigning fault to the victim ("it's her fault because she was dressed that way"), what is the fallacy of exonerating a person simply by virtue of being the victim? *Appeal to pity*?

Comment: Assigning blame is a matter of judgment rather than argument, so [victim blaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victim_blaming) is a psychological bias (prejudice) rather than a fallacy. There is no similar bias the other way, at least not as ingrained. The expression "victim whitewashing" is sometimes used to describe the effect.

Comment: why would we need to exonerate someone for being a victim? i suppose 'halo effect' or '[ad hominem](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56411/what-is-the-opposite-of-ad-hominem)' have relevance here? ps assigning blame can involve argument and rhetoric, though it may not be a philosophical question [cf nietzsche?]

Comment: it's not really a philosophical question imho, but i guess what you're asking is whether a gullible person who is conned has been stupid and is to blame for their misfortune. most people believe that extreme foolishness -- even if sincere -- is that person's fault: though that of course is an ad populum fallacy

Comment: anyway i downvoted. as well as being suggestive of hostile office politics, the question shows no research effort and is unhelpful

Comment: @another_name Actually this is question is in relation to this tweet: https://twitter.com/NHTSAgov/status/1214602204222500871

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda. I think that I did answer the question, though not particularly well. In order not to be both witness and judge, I have deleted my answer. This is an obvious requiremennt of impartiality. I have nothing more to say.